# Custom payment gateway with registerPaymentMethod

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to create a custom payment method with their new WooCommerce Blocks, but got stuck.

So, I've managed to setup the environment with WebPack, add plugin and inject custom payment fields:

```js
import { Fragment } from '@wordpress/element';

jQuery(function() {
    const Content = function({components}) {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className="form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label htmlFor="kbx-ean-number">EAN-nummer: <span className="required">*</span></label>
                    <input id="kbx-ean-number" name="kbx-ean-number" type="text" autoComplete="off" required="required" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label htmlFor="kbx-ean-user-id">Bruger: <span className="required">*</span></label>
                    <input id="kbx-ean-user-id" name="kbx-ean-user-id" type="text" autoComplete="off" required="required" />
                </div>
                <div className="clear"></div>
            </Fragment>
        );
    };

    const {registerPaymentMethod} = window.wc.wcBlocksRegistry;

    registerPaymentMethod({
        savedTokenComponent: <Fragment><p>say hi for savedTokenComponent</p></Fragment>,
        label: <Fragment><p>label</p></Fragment>,
        name: 'kbx-ean',
        ariaLabel: 'aria-Label',
        // content: Content,
        content: <Content />,
        edit: <Fragment><p>edit</p></Fragment>,
        canMakePayment: () => true,
    });
});
```

What I can't figure out - how to add custom data into the POST json?

Thank you.